# Set sourceCrossOrigin to all Pictures

Tags: gojs

I'm using Gojs 1.5.2.
I'm loading images on my canvas from S3. the bucket has CORS.

When I use `Diagram.makeImageData()` I get white blanks instead of my Images.
This is explained here - [makeImageData](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Diagram.html#makeImageData)

The solution is to use [sourceCrossOrigin](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Picture.html#sourceCrossOrigin) to anonymous, that seems to work.

Is there a way to define sourceCrossOrigin for all of my Picture classes in one place instead of each one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many examples use functions called things like `textStyle()` to make sure TextBlocks all have consistent properties set. See the code in [OrgChartEditor](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/orgChartEditor.html) for an example.

```
// This function provides a common style for most of the TextBlocks.
// Some of these values may be overridden in a particular TextBlock.
function textStyle() {
  return { font: "9pt  Segoe UI,sans-serif", stroke: "white" };
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
...
$(go.TextBlock, textStyle(),
  { row: 2, column: 0 },
  new go.Binding("text", "key", function(v) {return "ID: " + v;})),
$(go.TextBlock, textStyle(),
  { row: 2, column: 3, },
  new go.Binding("text", "parent", function(v) {return "Boss: " + v;})),
$(go.TextBlock, textStyle(),  // the comments
  {
...
```

---

Alternatively, you could override Picture. Here's an example:

```
function CustomPicture() {
  go.Picture.call(this);
  this.sourceCrossOrigin = function() { return 'anonymous' };
}
go.Diagram.inherit(CustomPicture, go.Picture);
```

Then use `$(CustomPicture,...` everywhere instead of `$(go.Picture,...`